# Blue border started showing around cell after iOS 13 update, how to get rid off it?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, email, constraints

I am going to try be precise about this problem.

I am fixing some old mail application written in objective c long time ago, and it worked pretty fine before this new iOS 13 update.

After that, it starts to show a blue border around body cell (where I have to type message).

I read about focus ring and it seems like same issue, but I was not quite sure because I did not see initialized it anywhere in my code.

Did anybody have a similar issue?

Thanks

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYc7S.png)

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes under UIKit.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it still stays the same. 
I will check it again, it might be that I did not edit values correctly.

Comment: Use the View Debugger to figure out _what_ is blue. There is no "focus ring" in the story. It's _your_ view.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but in my View Debugger there is no blue line like this in simulator and on real device. 
It is showing no matter which frames size I initialize.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer:

you need to implement these lines in your application:

[self.wkWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var style = document.createElement('style'); style.type = 'text/css'; style.innerHTML = '*:focus{ outline:none }'; document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);"];

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    canFocusRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> Bool {
    
    return false
    
}

func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    selectionFollowsFocusForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> Bool {
    
    return false
    
}
```